# Losing permissions by adding capability?

Tags: namespace, unshare

I observed the following phenomenon that I can not explain. After adding the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` capability, `unshare` is no longer able to write to `/proc/self/setgroups`.

In fact, writing to this file **requires** the capability, but that is achieved by changing the user namespace. So why does **adding** the capability to the parent process prevents writing to this file?

```
me@myhost:~$ unshare -r
root@myhost:~# exit
logout

me@myhost:~$ sudo setcap cap_sys_admin=ep /usr/bin/unshare
me@myhost:~$ unshare -r
unshare: cannot open /proc/self/setgroups: Permission denied

me@myhost:~$ sudo setcap cap_sys_admin= /usr/bin/unshare
me@myhost:~$ unshare -r
root@myhost:~#
```

**By the way:** I am running Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with kernel version 4.4 and the version of util-linux (including `unshare`) is 2.27.1.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/133922/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364568/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75045/ .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What's happening here is that your "unshare" process does not have access to write to the `setgroups` (and `uid_maps`, `gid_maps`) files on the *external* user namespace.

In that namespace, the pseudo-files in `/proc/<PID>` will be root-owned, and as if your effective uid is still that of your own user, you will not have access to write to those files.

You can visualize that easily by running a process in background (such as `sleep`) and inspecting the permissions of the `setgroups` file while it's running (`uid_maps` and `gid_maps` behave exactly the same.)

First, with a binary that doesn't have additional capabilities:

```
$ cp /usr/bin/sleep .
$ ./sleep 10 &
[1] 11209
$ ls -l /proc/11209/setgroups
-rw-r--r--. 1 myuser myuser 0 Jul 31 12:33 /proc/11209/setgroups
[1]+  Done                    ./sleep 10
$
```

Then, let's add some file capabilities to it and see the ownership change:

```
$ sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=ep sleep
$ ./sleep 10 &
[1] 11220
$ ls -l /proc/11220/setgroups 
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Jul 31 12:34 /proc/11220/setgroups
[1]+  Done                    ./sleep 10
$
```

The ownership of the files in `/proc/<PID>` is controlled by the "dumpable" flag inside the Linux kernel, which is used to prevent leaking information from a privileged process to an unprivileged user.

And considering you're running `unshare` with additional capabilities but still with a non-root *effective* uid, write access to these pseudo-files which are owned by root is prevented through the normal access controls of the operating system.

---

You can inspect the value of the "dumpable" flag by using the `PR_GET_DUMPABLE` command of the [prctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) syscall.

In the description for `PR_SET_DUMPABLE` you'll also find:

> Normally, this flag is set to 1.  However, it is reset to the current value contained in the file `/proc/sys/fs/suid_dumpable` (which by default has the value 0), in the following circumstances:
>
> [...]
>
> - The process executes (`execve(2)`) a program that has file capabilities (see [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html)), but only if the permitted capabilities gained exceed those already permitted for the process.

Which is exactly your case, with an `unshare` binary that has file capabilities.

Interestingly, using a root owned setuid binary for `unshare` doesn't run into this exact issue. Yes, it will clear the "dumpable" flags and the files in `/proc/<PID>` will be owned by root. But considering your effective uid is *also* root when running a setuid binary, the access will be allowed.

In that case, you end up running into a different problem, which has to do with `unshare`'s logic not being able to handle that particular setup (probably something to do with the effective uid and the actual uid not matching):

```
$ cp /usr/bin/unshare .
$ sudo setcap -r unshare
$ sudo chown root:root unshare
$ sudo chmod 4711 unshare
$ ./unshare -r
-bash: cannot set uid to 65534: effective uid 0: Invalid argument
-bash-4.4$
```

Also notice that the clearing of the "dumpable" flag was triggered by running a binary with file capabilities set. If you get additional capabilities in a different way, you might not run into this trouble. For instance, using "ambient" capabilities is a good way to get additional capabilities outside the namespace, while still not running into trouble when unsharing into a new user namespace.

(Unfortunately, there is not a lot of tooling around ambient capabilities yet. `libcap` only ships support in latest git, past version 2.25, which is the one currently shipped in most distros. `capsh` is fairly low-level, so it's not that easy to get it right either. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303738/281844) for details on using latest `capsh` to add ambient capabilities. I also tried `systemd-run` but couldn't really manage to get ambient capabilities set up there either. Anyways, something for you to look into, if you do need capabilities, non-root user & user namespaces together!)

Comment: thanks for mentioning [Ambient capabilities](https://lwn.net/Articles/635053/), for example that's interesting to avoid limitations described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux/414258#414258) to bind to a privileged port.